# Is there any additional security in storing user data in a separate database?

Tags: php, database, security

Specifically, I am working with PHP and data on a Web application.

As far as I can tell, the main reasons to access user data are:

- For logging in
- For communication, including shipping products

It seems to me that the sort of data most likely to be of interested to hackers is user data, so it deserves extra protection.

Here is a possible technique. I normally use PDO for database work, so the following should apply to any supported database.

- Create a database `users` with a single table of users.
- Create a user restricted to the database
- Create the PDO object accordingly
- From the main login script, call an included script which authenticates the user.

  - For added security, this script may be outside of the web root?
- Do the normal stuff using session variables. In particular store the relevant retrieved user info.
- Go ahead with the rest of the data from the main database

I don’t think all hosted servers make it easy to store anything outside of the web root.

My wild guess is that the user database is less likely to be compromised if it’s not part of the data most frequently accessed.

I also imagine that separating the user data from the password into separate tables is also a good idea, but I’ll put that into another question.

I’m not suggesting it’s a perfect solution, but I am looking for *better* protection. The question is: would a technique such as this provide more security than keeping the user details in the main database?

Comment: There are too many ways a data can be compromised. There is nothing inherently more secure keeping it in another database if SQL Injection is not possible unless the database is additionally siloed. However, database security is always a good thing to apply - this can be within the same database.

Comment: To append to @user2864740's comment, you could have multiple db user accounts only allowing specific databases, where 1 might be your user login details.

Answer (score 1):

You could write an authentication & authorisation service altogether.  Look at OAuth.  You authenticates with a username and password to this service and the auth server can generate tokens which enables access to your service.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth

Comment: I'm a big fan of this isolation (not necessarily OAuth, but an isolated service for AA/A). However it's all too uncommon.

Comment: We have a separate service for authorisation across all our different services.  But it's definitely a lot of work.  I personally thing you don't need a separate database altogether in your case.  Just hash the passwords well.  You can also using a different user to access the user table.  Remove access to the table for all other users.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, actually that is not a bad idea, but I would do this differently:

- Create database, user account to it and user data tables necessary.
- Create a different webhost(eg userapi.myhost), which could be even a local host. The new webhost should have its own web root in a complete different location from your main app.
- Create an API to get/change user data with a script(or use a framework) in the new host.
- Auth protect http requests to your API and restrict access to specific IP(even your local ip if the api is on the same server).
- Your main app uses the new API to access/change user data.

So, eg a user tries to login to the main app with user-password -> main app sends his login to the api -> if correct, get the info.

This can secure against sql injections, since your main app can have a lot of libraries and services that do a lot of different queries to your database and maybe some of them have security holes.
I would suggest:

- Keep the user API simple and tested.
- Keep the user admin on the secondary app(additionally password protect and restrict access to it to your ip).

Unfortunately, this does not secure you completely. There is a case where a hacker might place his own scripts or change your code, "see" the login details and access user data through your main app. Well, there are a lot of other ways, and a lot of different solutions. (apache openbase_dir restriction, remove write permissions for "apache" user to your code, remove execution handlers from directories "apache" user can write, eg images, etc)

Since you are looking for a better protection, I would sure suggest to go for it, if you do not mind to invest a little more work and time to it.